# Creating an edgelist from Patent data in R

Tags: r

I  am trying to create an edgelist out of patent data of the form:

```
PatentID    InventorIDs    CoinventorIDs

1           A ; B           C,D,E ; F,G,H,C

2           J ; K ; L       M,O ; N ; P, Q
```

What I would like is the edgelist below showing the connections between inventors and patents. (the semicolons separate the coinventors associated with each primary inventor):

```
1  A  B
1  A  C
1  A  D
1  A  E
1  B  F
1  B  G
1  B  H
1  B  C
2  J  K
2  J  L
2  J  M
2  J  O
2  K  N
2  L  P
2  L  Q
```

Is there an easy way to do this with igraph in R?

Comment: you have a data.frame? `dput()`.

Comment: igraph is the package for dealing with graphs in R. (Hope that's helpful; haven't used it myself.)

Comment: why are there edges from A->B and J->K, J->L but not from K->L?

Comment: Good catch. Those connections should be there as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm confused by the edges going between the inventorIds.  But, here is a kind of brute force function that you could just `apply` by row.  There may be a way with `igraph`, it being a massive library, that is better, but once you have the data in an this form it should be simple to convert to an `igraph` data structure.

Note that this leaves out the edges between primary inventors.

```
## A function to make the edges for each row
rowFunc <- function(row) {
    tmp <- lapply(row[2:3], strsplit, '\\s*;\\s*')
    tmp2 <- lapply(tmp[[2]], strsplit, ',')
    do.call(rbind, mapply(cbind, row[[1]], unlist(tmp[[1]]), unlist(tmp2, recursive=FALSE)))
}

## Apply the function by row
do.call(rbind, apply(dat, 1, rowFunc))
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#  [1,] "1"  "A"  "C" 
#  [2,] "1"  "A"  "D" 
#  [3,] "1"  "A"  "E" 
#  [4,] "1"  "B"  "F" 
#  [5,] "1"  "B"  "G" 
#  [6,] "1"  "B"  "H" 
#  [7,] "1"  "B"  "C" 
#  [8,] "2"  "J"  "M" 
#  [9,] "2"  "J"  "O" 
# [10,] "2"  "K"  "N" 
# [11,] "2"  "L"  "P" 
# [12,] "2"  "L"  " Q"
```

Comment: When I run this I get a table of the form   [1,] "1"  "A;B"   "C" 
 [2,] "1"  "A;B"   "D"  
 [3,] "1"  "A;B"   "E"

Comment: @afiimani Hi, perhaps a formatting issue with the data?  Can you provide the output of `dput(youData)` as an addendum to your original post?