# R apply function to each two elements each row in a data.frame -> edgelist

Tags: r, apply

I have a data.frame where each row is a group of people, between 2 and 8.
From this I want to create a graph showing all people as vertices and the edges showing that these two people occured in one row in my original data.frame.
The graph is not a problem, just the creation of the edgelist.
My question seems really close to [Creating an edgelist from Patent data in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33025418/creating-an-edgelist-from-patent-data-in-r)
, but since its my first day in R i can't close the gap from there.

my `data` look like this:

```
name_1  name_2  name_3  name_4  name_5
jan     tim         
tom     tim     bernd       
stefen  tom     tim     jan     bernd
marcel  bernd
```

output of `dput(data)`:

```
structure(list(name_1 = structure(c(1L, 4L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("jan", 
"marcel", "stefen", "tom"), class = "factor"), name_2 = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("bernd", "tim", "tom"), class = "factor"), 
    name_3 = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("", "bernd", 
    "tim"), class = "factor"), name_4 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L), .Label = c("", "jan"), class = "factor"), name_5 = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("", "bernd"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("name_1", 
"name_2", "name_3", "name_4", "name_5"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

as desired output i would like to have something like:

```
jan     tim
tom     tim
tom     bernd
tim     bernd
stefen  tom
stefen  tim
stefen  jan
stefen  bernd
tom     tim
tom     jan
tom     bernd
tim     jan
tim     bernd
marcel  bernd
```

duplicates are no problem to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we are using `combinations` function from gtools package.
 df1 is the given data frame.

```
# convert factor columns to character
df1 <- sapply(df1, as.character)

# get names per row which are not blank
df1 <- apply(df1, 1, function(x) toString(x[x != '']))

# save output to answer
answer <- list()

# we append the combination of names 
answer <- sapply(seq(df1), function(x) {

    print(df1[x])
    val <- unlist(strsplit(df1[x], split = ','))
    answer[[x]] <- combinations(n = length(val), r = 2, v = val,repeats.allowed = F)

})

# convert the list to df
df2 <- do.call('rbind', answer)
print(df2)

[1,] " tim"   "jan"   
 [2,] " bernd" " tim"  
 [3,] " bernd" "tom"   
 [4,] " tim"   "tom"   
 [5,] " bernd" " jan"  
 [6,] " bernd" " tim"  
 [7,] " bernd" " tom"  
 [8,] " bernd" "stefen"
 [9,] " jan"   " tim"  
[10,] " jan"   " tom"  
[11,] " jan"   "stefen"
[12,] " tim"   " tom"  
[13,] " tim"   "stefen"
[14,] " tom"   "stefen"
[15,] " bernd" "marcel"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few options. Firstly in base R, you can use `apply` to iterate over rows and `combn` to get combinations. Because your data is in an awkward configuration, you'll need a lot of code to stitch it together, though, e.g.

```r
df <- data.frame(name_1 = c("jan", "tom", "stefen", "marcel"), 
                 name_2 = c("tim", "tim", "tom", "bernd"), 
                 name_3 = c("", "bernd", "tim", ""), 
                 name_4 = c("", "", "jan", ""), 
                 name_5 = c("", "", "bernd", ""))

as.data.frame(
    do.call(rbind, 
            apply(df, 1, function(x){
                x <- x[x != '']; 
                t(combn(x, 2))
            })), 
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
#>        V1    V2
#> 1     jan   tim
#> 2     tom   tim
#> 3     tom bernd
#> 4     tim bernd
#> 5  stefen   tom
#> 6  stefen   tim
#> 7  stefen   jan
#> 8  stefen bernd
#> 9     tom   tim
#> 10    tom   jan
#> 11    tom bernd
#> 12    tim   jan
#> 13    tim bernd
#> 14    jan bernd
#> 15 marcel bernd
```

Technically it's better to use `Map` than `apply` (which coerces to a matrix), but that just requires more glue code here:

```r
as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, 
                      do.call(Map, 
                              c(function(...){
                                  x <- c(...);
                                  x <- x[x != '']; 
                                  t(combn(x, 2))
                              }, 
                              lapply(df, as.character)))), 
              stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
#>        V1    V2
#> 1     jan   tim
#> 2     tom   tim
#> 3     tom bernd
#> 4     tim bernd
#> 5  stefen   tom
#> 6  stefen   tim
#> 7  stefen   jan
#> 8  stefen bernd
#> 9     tom   tim
#> 10    tom   jan
#> 11    tom bernd
#> 12    tim   jan
#> 13    tim bernd
#> 14    jan bernd
#> 15 marcel bernd
```

Both approaches alternate between matrices and data frames liberally, which can get hard to keep track of. You can write an approach that avoids data frames entirely, but it's longer yet.

A prettier option is to use the tidyverse. First, tidy the data to long form:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df_tidy <- df %>% 
    mutate_all(as.character) %>% 
    mutate_all(na_if, '') %>% 
    rowid_to_column() %>% 
    gather(col, name, -rowid) %>% 
    drop_na(name) 

df_tidy
#>    rowid    col   name
#> 1      1 name_1    jan
#> 2      2 name_1    tom
#> 3      3 name_1 stefen
#> 4      4 name_1 marcel
#> 5      1 name_2    tim
#> 6      2 name_2    tim
#> 7      3 name_2    tom
#> 8      4 name_2  bernd
#> 10     2 name_3  bernd
#> 11     3 name_3    tim
#> 15     3 name_4    jan
#> 19     3 name_5  bernd
```

Much better. From this point, even a base approach is easier, e.g.

```r
as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, 
    aggregate(name ~ rowid, df_tidy, 
              function(x){list(t(combn(x, 2)))})$name))
```

Alternately, continue using the tidyverse, either with `combn`:

```r
df_tidy %>% 
    group_by(rowid) %>% 
    summarise(name = list(combn(name, 2, compose(as_data_frame, t), simplify = FALSE)), 
              name = map(name, bind_rows)) %>% 
    unnest(name)
#> # A tibble: 15 x 3
#>    rowid V1     V2   
#>    <int> <chr>  <chr>
#>  1     1 jan    tim  
#>  2     2 tom    tim  
#>  3     2 tom    bernd
#>  4     2 tim    bernd
#>  5     3 stefen tom  
#>  6     3 stefen tim  
#>  7     3 stefen jan  
#>  8     3 stefen bernd
#>  9     3 tom    tim  
#> 10     3 tom    jan  
#> 11     3 tom    bernd
#> 12     3 tim    jan  
#> 13     3 tim    bernd
#> 14     3 jan    bernd
#> 15     4 marcel bernd
```

...or with a less efficient but less complicated approach:

```r
df_tidy %>% 
    group_by(rowid) %>% 
    mutate(name2 = list(name)) %>% 
    unnest() %>% 
    filter(name < name2)
#> # A tibble: 15 x 4
#> # Groups:   rowid [4]
#>    rowid col    name   name2 
#>    <int> <chr>  <chr>  <chr> 
#>  1     1 name_1 jan    tim   
#>  2     3 name_1 stefen tom   
#>  3     3 name_1 stefen tim   
#>  4     2 name_2 tim    tom   
#>  5     4 name_2 bernd  marcel
#>  6     2 name_3 bernd  tom   
#>  7     2 name_3 bernd  tim   
#>  8     3 name_3 tim    tom   
#>  9     3 name_4 jan    stefen
#> 10     3 name_4 jan    tom   
#> 11     3 name_4 jan    tim   
#> 12     3 name_5 bernd  stefen
#> 13     3 name_5 bernd  tom   
#> 14     3 name_5 bernd  tim   
#> 15     3 name_5 bernd  jan
```

`tidyr::complete` can be used in a similar manner.